# Apache Camel quartz2 doesn't apply changed cron expression

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to use camel-quartz2 component in a cluster mode with JDBCJobStore.

**quartz.properties** file:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=JobCluster

org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=dsQuartzTest

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true

org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5
org.quartz.dataSource.dsQuartzTest.driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
org.quartz.dataSource.dsQuartzTest.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:pmuser@//10.13.13.10:1521/PDB1
org.quartz.dataSource.dsQuartzTest.user = pmuser
org.quartz.dataSource.dsQuartzTest.password = oracle
org.quartz.dataSource.dsQuartzTest.maxConnections = 10
```

**camel-context.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Configures the Camel Context-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <bean id="quartz2" class="org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent">
        <property name="propertiesFile" value="quartz.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="quartzBean" class="com.ubs.rbs.integration.QuartzBean"/>

    <camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <camel:route id="quartzRoute">
            <camel:from uri="quartz2://tictac?cron=0+0/5+*+1/1+*+?+*"/>
            <camel:setBody>
                <camel:simple>
                    ${header.triggerName} - ${header.fireTime}
                </camel:simple>
            </camel:setBody>
            <camel:to uri="log:hello"/>
        </camel:route>

<!--
        <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="timer://updateQuartzRoute?repeatCount=1"/>
            <camel:to uri="bean:quartzBean?method=reschedule(*,'quartzRoute')"/>
        </camel:route>
-->

    </camel:camelContext>

</beans>
```

When I first start the application, camel-quartz2 component schedules job with appropriate cron expression, and all works just OK. But, when I stop all instances of app, trigger remains in a WAITING state (it's, probably, OK for cluster, as component cannot tell when last instance is stopped, also, I cannot tell if this point is relevant, but without cluster it seems was no issue). So, when I start app next time trigger is already exists and its settings won't apply. Importantly, when I change cron expression and restart all instances, quartz uses old expression from DB, not new one from component's uri.

I found a workaround for this issue, using additional route (commented out in the xml above) to reschedule quartz in the custom bean as below:

```
public class QuartzBean {

    public void reschedule(CamelContext context, String quartzRouteId) throws Exception {
        QuartzEndpoint endpoint = (QuartzEndpoint) context.getRoute(quartzRouteId).getEndpoint();
        QuartzComponent component = endpoint.getComponent();
        Scheduler scheduler = component.getScheduler();

        Trigger oldTrigger = scheduler.getTrigger(endpoint.getTriggerKey());
        TriggerBuilder tb = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();

        Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(endpoint.getCron())).build();

        scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I can patch camel-quartz2 component as below (org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzEndpoint#addJobInScheduler):

```
private void addJobInScheduler() throws Exception {
    // Add or use existing trigger to/from scheduler
    Scheduler scheduler = getComponent().getScheduler();
    JobDetail jobDetail;
    boolean triggerExisted = scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey) != null;
    if (triggerExisted) {
        ensureNoDupTriggerKey();
    }

    jobDetail = createJobDetail();
    Trigger trigger = createTrigger(jobDetail);

    updateJobDataMap(jobDetail);

    // Schedule it now. Remember that scheduler might not be started it, but we can schedule now.
    Date nextFireDate = triggerExisted ? scheduler.rescheduleJob(triggerKey, trigger) : scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
        LOG.info("Job {} (triggerType={}, jobClass={}) is scheduled. Next fire date is {}",
                 new Object[] {trigger.getKey(), trigger.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                               jobDetail.getJobClass().getSimpleName(), nextFireDate});
    }

    // Increase camel job count for this endpoint
    AtomicInteger number = (AtomicInteger) scheduler.getContext().get(QuartzConstants.QUARTZ_CAMEL_JOBS_COUNT);
    if (number != null) {
        number.incrementAndGet();
    }

    jobAdded.set(true);
}
```

Unlike the current version in the project's repository, my version always creates new trigger and reschedules job if trigger already existed.

My questions are: Am I missing something obvious? How this component supposed to work in such scenario? Should I try to change component itself or is there a better way to change its schedule from outside?

UPD: I tried versions 2.13.1 from maven and 2.14.SNAPSHOT from sources.

Answer (score 0):

Camel versions 2.12.2 and before have known bugs related to Quartz. Give 2.12.3 and upwards a try, if you're not.

Comment: I tried versions 2.13.1 from maven and 2.14.SNAPSHOT from sources.

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7627 along with patch and unit test.